# .submit() not working in Firefox can't append to body

Tags: jquery, html

My problem is that `('id_form').submit()` is not triggered. It's working fine on Chrome but not on Firefox. I know similar questions were posted but the response was always for a form which was directly attached to the body which is not my case as you see in my html.

```
<body>
    <div class="sitecontainer">

        form-vehicule

        <div class="body">
            <!-- NBA_dataLayer_v1 -->
            <section class="slice-pn7 slice-full-size no-margin-top">
                <div class="header">
                    <header>
                        <div>
                            <h1><span class="bold">Tasación Peugeot</span></h1>
                        </div>
                    </header>
                </div>
            </section>

            <div class="container-fluid ">
                <form id="form-vehicule" class="form-vehicule" name="form_vehicule" method="post" action="http://tasacion.peugeot.shakazoola.com/">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <h2 class="text-left">INDICA EL NÚMERO DE PUERTAS DE TU VEHÍCULO</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row ">
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
                            <button type="button" data-scope="select_vo_porte" class="button button-porte-boite btn-cta grey select_vo_porte scrollPage" style="" value="3">3 puertas</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
                            <button type="button" data-scope="select_vo_porte" class="button button-porte-boite btn-cta grey select_vo_porte scrollPage" style="" value="5">5 puertas</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row margin-top" id="toScroll">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <h2 class="text-left">SELECCIONA EL TIPO DE CAJA DE CAMBIO</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row " id="resultBoite">
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
                            <button type="button" data-scope="select_vo_boite" class="button button-porte-boite btn-cta  dark-blue" style="" value="1">Manual</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" style="margin-top:2em;">
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
                            <div class="inline-cta">
                                <a id="back_slide" class="cta btn-cta arrow grey previous">
                                    <span class="content-cta">ANTERIOR</span> 
                                </a> 
                            </div>  
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-3 col-md-offset-6  col-lg-2  col-lg-offset-8">         
                            <div class="inline-cta">
                                <a id="submit_slide" class="cta btn-cta arrow light-blue next" onclick="javascript:void(0);">
                                    <span class="content-cta"> SIGUIENTE</span> 
                                </a> 
                            </div>                
                        </div>      
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end body !-->
    </div>
</body>
```

so `('#form-vehicule').appendTo('body');` is not working to make the submit succeed. It's actually moving the form to the end of the body

you can check the whole js file at this url http://tasacion.peugeot.shakazoola.com/assets/js/formcheck.js

Comment: are you asking why submit won't work, or why append to body won't work?  your question is unclear.

Comment: I am asking why the submit won't work . and explainig that I used The append solution . just edited my question to make it clearer

Comment: We don't want to check the "*whole [js] file,*" we expect you to do your best to try and work out approximately where the problem is and post the "*[mcve]*" code to reproduce your problem.

Comment: If you append the form to the body after page load, then you can try this : $(document).on("submit", "form_id", function() {  code   })

Comment: there is no use in checking the js the problem is about fretching a solution working to submit the form on firefox and I'm explaining that the appendTo('body') solution did not work for me I guessed That posting the html to see the parents of the form clearly is more useful

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use this to append it to the class of body:

```
$('#form-vehicule').appendTo('.body');
```

For the form submit, you should use make sure to bind the click event similar to how SK Jajoriya suggested:

```
    $(document).on('click', '#submit_slide', function() {
        $(this).parents('form').submit();
    });
```

or if it is the button elements:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.button', function() {
        $(this).parents('form').submit();
    });
```

Using this approach, the bound click event will fire regardless if the form existed when the page loaded or if it was injected after the event bind occurred.

Hope this helps.